# Extract Month Intervals out of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string from a user input containing intervals in months like below

```
#example to user input
'some text here Jul-21 to September-2021 some more text'
#or
'some text july 2021 - sep21 some more text'
```

as mentioned above the above string come from a user input so there is no specific format of the string. However the interval should come in somewhat this format `'[some text] [month (full or first 3 letters)][- or space][years (4 or 2 digit)][to or -][month (full or first 3 letters)][- or space][years (4 or 2 digit)]'`. Is there a pythonic way to extract the intervals in this format `'[month (first 3 letters)]-[years (2 digit)] to [month (first 3 letters)]-[years (2 digit)]'` from the above string?

```
#expected string
'Jul-21 to Sep-21'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can start with using some simple regex as followed

```
import re

my_str = 'some text here Jul-21 to sep-2021 some more text'
months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec']
matches = re.findall(''.join([m + "-\d+|" for m in months]), my_str.lower())
print([m for m in matches if m])
```

out`['jul-21', 'sep-2021']`

but this isn't full-proof, as your input is much more elaborate. you could in theory enhance the regex (add more cases to `months` arr for example)

Comment: the above answer is partially correct, however i experimented by changing the regex line to ```matches = re.findall(''.join([m[:-1] + ".|" for m in months]), my_str.lower())``` which works for the most part except it ignores the year. This new code can work for a year and i will keep changing the code slighty to cope up with the year change until i come up with a better solution. Thanks for the idea though